# How to implement pages in Java Swing app.?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, layout-manager

I have some experience in Java creating Apps and would like to learn more, and so have decided to create an application that will have different pages. For example the initial frame will show a menu of buttons that will lead to different frames, showing different components and layouts.

I'm not too sure the best practice of implementing pages. I think I could store the `JFrame` windows in a list, then use a button handler class to maybe change the visibility of the different frames, only allowing the relevant frame to be visible when the user clicks on a button. I think this method could work, but is there a more efficient/practical way of doing this?

I am aware of `CardLayout`, however for this program I am trying to learn `MigLayout`; so that won't be possible (as far as I'm aware). I hope this question is not too vague, I'd just like to know the best practice when it comes to creating applications in Java with different pages.

Comment: 1) Yes you can use CardLayout. The panel with the CardLayout is the "parent" panel. Then you have child panels you add to the CardLayout. These panels can use whatever layout manger they want. 2) Don't use multiple frames. If you need separate windows then you should be using a JDialog as a child window.

Comment: There's any number of ways you "might" do this. `CardLayout` is certainly an option, but doesn't always fit every situation (nothing ever does). Sometimes you need to "roll your own" solution, which might use a model and controller to manage a collection of views.  This would be some what more dynamic in nature, but would require more work on you end to make it work

Answer (score 0):

Can use Tabbed Panes, it is the best for storing pages.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/tabbedpane.html

Also I noticed that you need to consider top level containers properly, because you don't need to create every time a JFrame for each Page, at least if it was necessary(For example: an editor, create a new window so you need to create a new JFrame, in your case I don't think so) so please consider the link below.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/toplevel.html

Answer (score 0):

**JInternalFrame** is a part of Java Swing . JInternalFrame is a container that provides many features of a frame which includes displaying title, opening, closing, resizing, support for menu bar, etc. [Internal frames with components example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XAfwm.png)

Code  to create multiple internal frames:

```
import java.awt.event.*; 
import java.awt.*; 
import javax.swing.*; 

class solution extends JFrame { 

// frame 
static JFrame f; 

// label to diaplay text 
static JLabel l, l1; 

// main class 
public static void main(String[] args) { 
    // create a new frame 
    f = new JFrame("frame"); 

    // set layout of frame 
    f.setLayout(new FlowLayout()); 

    // create a internal frame 
    JInternalFrame in = new JInternalFrame("frame 1", true, true, true, true); 

    // create a internal frame 
    JInternalFrame in1 = new JInternalFrame("frame 2", true, true, true, true); 

    // create a Button 
    JButton b = new JButton("button"); 
    JButton b1 = new JButton("button1"); 

    // create a label to display text 
    l = new JLabel("This is a JInternal Frame no 1  "); 
    l1 = new JLabel("This is a JInternal Frame no 2  "); 

    // create a panel 
    JPanel p = new JPanel(); 
    JPanel p1 = new JPanel(); 

    // add label and button to panel 
    p.add(l); 
    p.add(b); 
    p1.add(l1); 
    p1.add(b1); 

    // set visibility internal frame 
    in.setVisible(true); 
    in1.setVisible(true); 

    // add panel to internal frame 
    in.add(p); 
    in1.add(p1); 

    // add internal frame to frame 
    f.add(in); 
    f.add(in1); 

    // set the size of frame 
    f.setSize(300, 300); 

    f.show(); 
} 
}
```